# Is there an official 3E D&D character builder?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tools, tool-recommendation

Is there an official D&D 3E character generator online or downloadable?  (Not just a character sheet or tracker.)

If there are no official generators, is there a good one anywhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three big ones.

[Hero Lab from Lone Wolf Development](http://www.wolflair.com/index.php?context=hero_lab) is IMO the best character generator for D&D 3.5e and Pathfinder. It's being actively developed, has a large community, and is professional quality. It supports a wide variety of rulesets including 3.5e, 4e, Pathfinder, Mutants & Masterminds, World of Darkness, Call of Cthulhu, and Savage Worlds. You can download it and use it in demo mode, which doesn't allow you to save or print.

I have also used [RPGXplorer](http://www.rpgxplorer.com/) and [PCGen](http://pcgen.sourceforge.net/01_overview.php).  PCGen is free and is decent, it's a freeware distant second to Hero Lab, and I really didn't like RPGXplorer, the interface was very unintuitive to me. You can try it yourself, it has a demo mode that works fully featured up to level 5.

Answer (score 9):

The venerable (and free!) [PCGen](http://pcgen.sourceforge.net/01_overview.php) will make characters for multiple versions of D&D and similar d20-based systems.

Answer (score 4):

There was an official one for 3.0 (a demo of it came in my 3.0 book as a bind-in). I have n idea how well it works, as I didn't have a WINE implementation to run it until after I'd quit running 3.X.

I recall hearing that it was later updated to 3.5.

Comment: FWIW, I remember the demo version for 3e was a little clunky.  WoTC later sold eTools for 3e (and I'll assume 3.5), that was a little persnickety, but essentially was MUCH more powerful.

Comment: The demo was limited to level 3 characters, too.