# Who composed the music for the CD attached with 3e Player's Handbook?

Tags: history-of-gaming, dnd-3e, music, generator

Goal:
I'd like to find the full audio track/collection to listen to, if possible.

Details and research:
Also called "Character Generator" or "E-Tools", here is [a link to a clip of the music](https://youtu.be/jRZkPzjoMKk).

I have done a few Google searches so far, with (I believe) the most relevant results from "3e character generator demo music".

Referenced [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/7006/71430), but no mention of the author or to where the product was sold.

Also referenced [here](https://seangamingcorner.blogspot.com/2016/10/old-ad-2nd-edition-character-creation.html) with more screenshots.

I found [more detailed info](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=11971) on the demo program, but still no direct mention of the music author.

Also, this is [a broader history of the demo CD](https://dungeonsdragons.fandom.com/wiki/E-Tools).

Comment: [This CD?](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?editionid=13426)

Comment: Yes, this is the CD @Trish

Comment: @MarsPlastic Not to take anything away from Trish’s fantastic answer, but if you enjoyed that, you might enjoy [the likely holy grail of SE answer research, the identity of the “evil 3’s” sci-fi story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105743/7700).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The software history

The software was made around [1999 to 2001](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?editionid=13426) by [Fluid Entertainment](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/125954/dd-e-tools-character-and-monster-generator) (see the back of the cover). The company had the software [on their portfolio till around 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20130918212204/http://www.fluidentertainment.com/past-products/Dungeons.html) when the webpage vanished. Around 2003 or such, Wizards brought [a different developer](http://web.archive.org/web/20050310142853/http://www.codemonkeypublishing.com/index.php?module=htmlpages&func=display&pid=10) in to fix issues and broaden the scope - but those don't seem to be the addition of music. That contract lapsed in 2006.

#### Fluid Entertainment

Fluid Entertainment was founded in 1998, so E-tools was kind of the first steps for them. The company portfolio in 2013 was mostly web-games, and [LinkedIn still lists three employees](https://www.linkedin.com/company/fluid-entertainment/about/). One of the three employees is described as "recording artist, song writer, classic car builder at fluid entertainment".

With this little information, it appears as if the music was either contracted for or made in-house, but maybe I can take a look at the files itself...

### Dissecting the files?

#### The Fluid-Entertainment Archive

The Webarchive allows [downloading the 1.2 files as hosted by Fluid Entertainment](http://web.archive.org/web/20130918212204/http://www.fluidentertainment.com/downloads/D&D%20Char%20Gen%201.zip). However, this archive doesn't install on a modern machine due to a DirectX error ("The DirectX folder does not exist on your Media"), even trying to emulate an XP machine. The .cab files don't open as cabinet files either. As a result, I can't try to look at the files from data2.cab which seems to be the one that contains the music - if it is there.

The best information we get from this archive without a working installation/installed file is from the Readme.txt:

> The computer software, artwork, **music**, and other components included in
> this product (collectively the "Software") are the copyrighted property
> of Wizards of the Coast, Inc. ("Wizards").

So, even if Fluid Entertainment was the original source of the music, it was possibly work-for-hire for Wizards of the Coast.

#### The Archived CDs

However, the 1.2 Demonstration CD *also* is archived as [1.0](https://archive.org/details/Dungeons_and_Dragons_Character_Generation_Demonstration_Version_1.0_FluidWiza) and [1.2](https://archive.org/details/dndchargenv12demo) in the Web Archive. These CD images are formated differently and have to be either turned into a physical CD again or mounted in a virtual drive.

The 1.2 Demonstration CD *does* contain the proper DirectX file, installs **and** runs on a modern machine! So now the delving in the files can begin:

There is exactly one file in the path `\Wizards of the Coast\D&D Character Generator Demo\Resources\Music`: **Menu.mp3**

However, that file only has very little metadata: a length of 53 seconds, a Bitrate of 128 bit, and created on 28th of April 2000, 08:14. Author or interpreter are missing.

The file `\Wizards of the Coast\D&D Character Generator Demo\Resources\Audio.pak` does not compute as a valid archive.

However, there *is* an answer: The program has a **Credits** function, and that contains the answer:

> #### Sound Design & Production
>
> **Paul Gorman**

Apparently, this is the same [Paul Gorman](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0331115/) that also made the Forgotten Realms: Baldur's Gate - Dark Alliance soundtrack in 2001, the Neverwinter Nights soundtrack in 2002 and SW:KotOR in 2003. [According to LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/paul-gorman-7a88551/), he ran Duff Studios from 1999 to 2003, which would mean he was most likely a contractor for Fluid Entertainment.

In particular, he is [credited](https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/pokmon-play-it-version-2/credits) [twice](https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/pokmon-play-it-version-2/credits) to have made the sounds for the two Pokémon card games made by Fluid Entertainment in 1999 and 2000, establishing that he most likely worked with or for them in the right timeframe. Both these games were *also* made for Wizards of the Coast as interactive tutorials for these card-IPs.

Comment: The further research that went into this post's development was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124917/discussion-between-trish-and-avi-drucker)

Comment: We stand in awe. Around that time, I was still using Windows 98SE on my home machine.